# Не прорисовывается карта в игре на c++

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

У меня есть массив строк, который и является картой:

```
const int H = 25;
const int W = 40;

String TileMap[H] = {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0                                      0",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
};
```

Также есть цикл, производящий прорисовку этой карты:

```
for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
    {
        if (TileMap[i][j] == ' ') rectangle.setFillColor(Color::Black);
        if (TileMap[i][j] == 's')  rectangle.setFillColor(Color::Green);
        if ((TileMap[i][j] == '0')) continue;

        rectangle.setPosition(j * 32, i * 32);
        screen.draw(rectangle);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что ничего не прорисовывается, хотя по всей логике должно.
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А Вы задали размер для `rectangle` при создании?

Comment: Эммм по умолчанию задний фон черный в sfml...

Comment: Bruh, я неправильно указал размер rectangle, спасибо!